# Load Select list into IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a Selectlist populated from a class which I use elsewhere in my app however I want to load the values of it into an Ienumerable can anyone advise how to do this

I have my Select list like so

```
public SelectList doSomething(int param)
{
  var defaultOptions = Options.GetDefaultOptions(param);
  return new SelectList(defaultOptions.ToArray(), "Option");
}
```

I can set the property in my model manually like so

```
model.Options = new[] {"10,"12"};
```

how can i get this populated from doSomething
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
model.Options = doSomething(5).Cast<SelectListItem>().Select(item => item.Value);
```

or simply:

```
model.Options = doSomething(5).Select(item => item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a project (`Select()`) that returns the required property (string). Then use `ToArray()` to create an array.

```
model.Options = doSomething(123).Items.Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
```